# Using a function in Java8 map

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a Java8 equivalent way of writing the following?

```
List<Foo> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (RowResult row : rows) {
   results.add(rowToFooFunction(classroomLookup.get(row.getId()), studentLookup.get(row.getId())).apply(row));
}
```

Where the rowToFooFunction is like `Function<RowResult, Foo> rowToFoo (Classroom c, Student s)...`

So I would like to end up with something like:

```
rows.stream.map(rowToFooFunction...).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem is, in the map step, I need to lookup the student/classroom by the id of the row i am iterating over.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm sorry, what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost found the solution yourself already, you are very close:

```
List<Foo> results = rows.stream().map(row ->
  rowToFooFunction(classroomLookup.get(row.getId()), studentLookup.get(row.getId())).apply(row))
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```